# Can not display utf8 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to insert our data in Databse using MySQL and MySQL Workbench. Problem is even though I had set utf8_general_ci for both database and table, it didn't work. I tried to export it to a .sql file and opened with gedit but the same problem.

```
     ALTER DATABASE ShopDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
     ALTER TABLE ShopDB.PRODUCTS CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

UPDATE: THANKS to all, I fixed it now. Problem is in my Java code JDBC Driver. Sorry for bad question and taking your time.

Comment: Run SHOW CREATE TABLE; please, as the character set coul dbe specified at field's level

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?  If you've inserted data with using the wrong encoding (e.g. stored the bytes reasulting from utf8-encoding as latin1 characters) then changing the encoding won't undo that.

Comment: I mean I changed the encoding to utf8 before insert data into database. I've check all the table and columns, they would be encoded by utf8 format before I start inserting data. @Michael-sqlbot